# Refactoring read write accessors from/to one data member

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, std

I would like to refactor the accessors in following structure:

```
template<class T>
class ValueTime {
public:
   // accessors for val:
   const T& get_val() const { return val; }
   template<class V> void set_val(const V& v) { val = v; }
   // other accessors for tp

private:
   T val;
   std::chrono::system_clock::time_point now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
};
```

I would like to make the accessors to the `val` data members more useful and intuitive, mostly from the point of view of the "standard/boost user expectations" of such structure representing a "value in time":

1. `template<class V = T> V get_val() { return V(val); }`
2. `T& operator*() & { return val; }`
3. `const T& operator*() const & { return val; }`

Now I can use the accessors this way (see the comments):

```
int main() {
    ValueTime<double> vt;

    // get_val() no longer returns const ref and also
    // allows explicit cast to other types
    std::chrono::minutes period{vt.get_val<int>()}; // I had to use the more pedantic static_cast<int> with the original version

    // let's use operator*() for getting a ref.
    // I think that for a structure like a ValueTime structure,
    // it's clear that we get a ref to the stored "value"
    // and not to the stored "time_point"
    auto val = *vt; // reference now;
    val = 42;
}
```

Is the getter more usueful now? Do you see anything strange or unsafe or counterintuitive in the new interface (apart from being non backward compatible, which I do not care)?

Furthermore, one doubt I still have is if it's better to implement `get_val()` by returning `V(val)` or `V{val}` or just `val`. As it is now, it works if V has an explicit constructor. What do you think about this issue?

Comment: The answer(s) would depend on the purpose of `ValueTime`, which remains mysterious. Why can't you use functionality provided by `std`? Does `ValueTime` have more data members (what is `tp` mentioned in the comment of the original code)? What is the meaning of `ValueTime::val`?

Answer (score 0):

I personally would advise you to make the interface as *descriptive* as possible and avoid any convenient conversions to reference of data or similar.
The reason is simply usability and maintenance. If you or somebody else are (re-)visiting code using `ValueTime`, when you cannot remember the precise interface, you still want to understand your code without re-visiting the definition of `ValueTime`.

There is a difference to members from `std` (such as `std::vector`) is that you know their definition by heart.